# XFS and zero bytes files

Tags: filesystems, xfs, corruption

I am trying to establish what has happened to my data.

Before I go into the history, can anyone explan the discrepency between these two outputs;

```
# du --si /var/media/footage/k0/09/99/88
1.6G    /var/media/footage/k0/09/99/88
```

and

```
 ls -ltr /var/media/footage/k0/09/99/88
total 1501128
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  9 16:38 k0099988-4k.mov
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 10 15:57 k0099988-hd.mov
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 10 15:58 k0099988-preview.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 10 15:58 k0099988-wmprev.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 10 15:58 k0099988-thumb.mp4
```

Why does `du` report 1.6Gb but all the files are zero bytes?

**The History**
I received a message from my storage system that "Unwritable write-back cache data exists for a volume. (disk group: unknown name, volume: unknown name, SN: 00c0ff287a86000004815a5901000000) It comprises 1% of cache space."

Soon after the LVM volume (123Tb) went off-line. I had to reboot the server to get the volume to mount again. When I did I noticed thousands of files were 0 bytes in size. The LVM volume is made up of two PVs; 101Tb and 23Tb. The corruption seems to have affected newer files that I'd suspect would be in the 23Tb PV as that was added more recently. The files themselves are written to disk and rarely accessed. When the are accessed, they are readonly. Most access to the filesystem is RO via NFS.

We had a similar incident about a month ago but will less damage. The underlying storage system (HP MSA) reports no issues.

I've run `xfs_check` over the volume over-night it was still running 12 hours later so I stopped it. Nothing has changed.

Do I need to go to my backups or is there some magic to get my data back? Is this a file-system problem or should I be looking at the hardware? Are there things I should be doing more regularly to minimise such events?

Thanks in advance,
Dermot

```
CentOS release 6.3

XFS_INFO (v3.1.1)
meta-data=/dev/mapper/video2-lv01 isize=256    agcount=123, agsize=268435455 blks
         =                       sectsz=4096  attr=2, projid32bit=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=32947259392, imaxpct=1
         =                       sunit=1      swidth=256 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=521728, version=2
         =                       sectsz=4096  sunit=1 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

Comment: "Why does du report 1.6Gb but all the files are zero bytes?" There could be hidden files whose names start with a dot. Add the `-a` option to list them.

Comment: `-a` doesn't show anything. There are no hidden files in these directories. Also note that `ls` shows a similar total